# Null data table

Tags: r, data.table

I have the following data.table (data6):

```
> head (data6)
   sequenceID transactionID eventID
1:   36652675          2862       1
2:   38763251            68       1
3:   39535156        113964       1
4:   39535156        113965       2
5:   39535156        113966       3
6:   39535156        113967       4
                                                                                                             items
1:                                                                         34D89F927092290A5DA9B108F7020C19 SELECT
2:                                           15873DB37BF80750C70B68A8778B9DC01D548B6D06E3BF92CADAFF289B3FCAEE CALL
3:                                                                         005C9FFB9292EDFF0356C4326B14CA06 SELECT
4:                                           9AD4E96D7EF2FC7B64407EAF4E2274868B2C0545BFBA9F15F828D9986D484A4D CALL
5: 828F0D137BDA57F7F4F02801B0E51FDEDCB610BC734FE31D26399E5CBCE651FF SELECT;5BD81A7A48EDA2B8E56100CE844D3BE7 SELECT
6: 828F0D137BDA57F7F4F02801B0E51FDEDCB610BC734FE31D26399E5CBCE651FF SELECT;5BD81A7A48EDA2B8E56100CE844D3BE7 SELECT
```

I use the following command:

```
data6<-setDT(data6)[,if(any(eventID>2)) .SD , sequenceID][,names(data),with=FALSE]
```

And I get as a result:

```
> data6
Null data.table (0 rows and 0 cols)
```

Why is it?

Comment: What is `data`?  I meant `names(data)`  If it is a typo `[, names(data6), with=FALSE]` works fine

Comment: I think you find my mistake!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @akrun,
I related to names(data) instead of names(data6). 
The corrected command:

```
data6<-setDT(data6)[,if(any(eventID>2)) .SD , sequenceID][,names(data6),with=FALSE]
```